# Is a central web server required for hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a question regarding composer application architecture.

A typical composer application consists of three parts:

- blockchain network
- central web server (e.g. composer-rest-server)
- web client (e.g. Angular)

Is the central web server absolutely necessary?
It looks like a user has to trust this central web server with his ID card.
If this server is compromised, the digital identity of all user who put their ID cards on this server could be compromised.

This may be fine if the user is part of an organisation which runs and secures its own server.
But what happens if the user is not part of such an organisation? Is he required to trust some central authority with his ID card?

Would it be possible to omit the central server and let the web client work with the blockchain directly? This would be similar to how dApps work in Ethereum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of discussion on RocketChat ...

It is not necessayy to have a Central REST server - each participating organisation can have their own REST server, and they can have separate and different authentication methods chosen by the organisation.

Alternatively, the REST server can be omitted completely by writing a Web App against the Javascript API which has all the functionality to manage cards and connectivity to the Business Network.

Authentication and access to the Business Network does require Business Network cards (unless complete unauthenticated anonymous access is allowed!) and these do have to be issued using an administrative ID.

There is a [blog example](https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc) of how a self-service facility could be setup, and with an appropriate model and ACLs some lockdown can be achieved.